# Two forms submit to the same controller update action in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I have two form for updating users table.

Each form update different columns and the routes are as following:

```
Route::get('users/preferences', 'Auth\AuthController@pref');
Route::get('users/profile/{id}/edit', 'Auth\AuthController@edit');
Route::patch('users/profile/{id}', 'Auth\AuthController@update');
```

both form actions to this route: *users/profile/{id}*

Is there a way I can identify which form is submitted and therefore I can apply validate or manipulate data before inserting?

**Note:** I do not need the id in preferences because I used the current logged in ID in this case.

```
public function pref()
{
    return view('pages.users.pref');
}

public function edit(User $id)
{
    return view('pages.users.edit')->with('profile', $id);
}

public function update(Request $request, User $id)
{
    // want to know of best way to know which form is submitted
    /*
    if(this from)
         do this
    else 
         do that
    */

    return redirect('users/profile/'.$id->userid);
}
```

If you have a better idea please provide. 
Thanks in advance.

Comment: I assume you're looking for [this](https://laravel.com/docs/5.1/requests#basic-request-information). More specifically `if ($request->isMethod('<method goes here>')){...}`

Comment: add a hidden form field to both of the forms with different values then based on that field value do the action you need

Comment: @Andrew is that will return method type post/get/patch but both of them are patch method

Comment: @K.Toress I thought of that but is it secure to do so? and is it the best way to handle this? If in future I want to add one more form to the same action this will help?

Comment: @ClearBoth Well if you're using 2 routes with the same method and the same name, it will not work, ever. As far as I know anyway. The first route will take priority over the second route. Unless you hack your way thru it, which I don't recommend.

Comment: @Andrew no duplicate routes just submitting to the same from both form <form method="post" action="{{ url('users/profile/'.$user->id) }}">

Comment: @ClearBoth Oh, I see, I see. In that case, K.Toress's answer is the right choice. It should be secure enough, since you can literally do `if(case1)` and `if(case2)`. Even if somebody would mess with the front-end it won't matter that much.

Comment: if you update the same table but have differnt feels just update $request->all() and nothing bad would happen right? If you have validation in between just check for a preset hidden field as described before